# Displaying one to many relationship in razor Edit View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an entity called Person who has a list of colours. The colours have a name and active field. When I edit a person I want to be able to edit the colours attached to them. I'm having trouble doing this in the razor view - as I am getting errors.

```
@model InterviewTest.Domain.Entities.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Person</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonId)




    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAuthorised, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsAuthorised)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsAuthorised, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsEnabled)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to attempt it doing this - but not working.

```
    <h2>Favourite Colours</h2>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Colours)
    { 
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(item.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(item.IsEnabled)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(item.)` should  be `@Html.EditorFor(item.Name)` ? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @amarduplantier no its the Labelfor not I'm getting "Error 2 The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. 
"

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. It is incomplete in the following div

```
<div class="checkbox">
 @Html.EditorFor**(item.)**
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Rather use **item.Name**

Comment: Sorry that was left blank because of error above it, i've updated the post

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure whether the properties in Colour class is all public and whether the isEnabled property exists.

Looking at  your code it seems like IsAuthorised and IsEnabled property is available for the Model i.e the Person entity.

But in the forearch item in Model.Colours you are trying to use IsEnabled for an item i.e in this case it is Colour entity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the lambda expression in the LabelFor and EditorFor? You used it everywhere else.
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsAuthorised)`